# How to write better sequential promise calls in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, synchronization, angular-promise

What is a clean way to write a code like this? For multiple times I have to use the response of previous request to build a new URL and elastic search query from different sources and tables.

```
$scope.whatIFinallyWant = {};
$http.get(url1).then(function(response1){
    // creating new url2 & query with response1
    $http.get(url2).then(function(response2){
        // creating new url3 & query with response2
        $http.get(url3).then(function(response3){
            // creating new url4 & query with response3
            $http.get(url4).then(function(response4){
                // using the final response in UI ... 
                $scope.whatIFinallyWant = response4;
            }) 
        }) 
    }) 
})
```

Comment: `synchronous promise` - Promises are asynchronous by design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain the promises like so

```
$scope.whatIFinallyWant = {};
$http.get(url1)
.then(function(response1) {
    // creating new url2 & query with response1
    return $http.get(url2);
}).then(function(response2) {
    // creating new url3 & query with response2
    return $http.get(url3);
}).then(function(response3) {
    // creating new url4 & query with response3
    return $http.get(url4);
}).then(function(response4){
    // using the final response in UI ... 
    $scope.whatIFinallyWant = response4;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since $http.get() returns resolved data ( please checkout angular docs for it's exact shape: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), you might use predefined function to form url and call $http.get():

```
let makeUrl = (promiseResult) => {
  let url
  /* some logic */
  return $http.get(url);
}

let logErr = (err) => {
    console.error("Whoops! " + err);
}

$http.get(url1)
  .then(makeUrl)
  .then(makeUrl)
  .then(makeUrl)
  .then((finalUrl) => {
     $scope.whatIFinallyWant = finalUrl;
  })
  .catch(logErr)
```

Comment: everytime the logic to create a new url and query is very different. not possible to use a function for all of those processes.

Comment: also, `$scope.whatIFinallyWant` will be a promise, rather than `response4`